# Missing 1 required positional argument in python Constructor

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn inheritance concept in python. I have an Employee class and derivative class Executive.

```
class Employee:
    'Class defined for employee'

    def __init__(self, name, dept, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.dept = dept
        self.salary = salary
```

Subclass

```
class Executive(Employee):

    def __init__(self, name, dept, salary, hascar):
        Employee.__init__(name, dept, salary)
        self.hascar = hascar
```

has car is a Boolean passed into the constructor, However this will give me an error:

> File "I:\Python_practicals\com\python\oop\Executive.py", line 7, in
>   **init**
>       Employee.**init**(name, dept, salary) TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'salary'

When I try to Instantiate an object of Executive.

`emp4 = Executive("Nirmal", "Accounting", 150000, True)`

Answer (score 7):

While `__init__` is an instance method, you're calling it on the *class* rather than on an instance. This invocation is called *unbound*, because it is not *bound* to an instance. Because of this, you need to explicitly pass `self`:

```
class Executive(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, dept, salary, hascar):
        Employee.__init__(self, name, dept, salary)
#                         ^^^^
        self.hascar = hascar
```

The recommended way, however, is to use [`super`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class.

With `super` your code would look like this:

```
class Executive(Employee):

    def __init__(self, name, dept, salary, hascar):
        super(Executive, self).__init__(name, dept, salary)
#       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        self.hascar = hascar
```

Python 3 adds some syntactic sugar to make this common parent class invocation simpler:

```
class Executive(Employee):

    def __init__(self, name, dept, salary, hascar):
        super().__init__(name, dept, salary)  # Py 3
#       ^^^^^^^
        self.hascar = hascar
```

Comment: In case python3 `super()` has much simpler syntax. `super().__init__(name, dept, salary)`

Comment: I'm aware, but the OP tagged the question Python 2.7 so I have started with the compatible syntax.

Comment: Oh haven't seen that. Sorry !. he also tagged python 3.x for some reason

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.x
Use `super()` keyword. This will let you avoid typing the Base class explicitly. makes the code more maintainable.

```
class Executive(Employee):

    def __init__(self, name, dept, salary, hascar):
        super().__init__(name, dept, salary)
        self.hascar = hascar
```